# Statistics and machine learning references which require functional analysis background

Tags: mathematical-statistics, references

I am doing a PhD in functional analysis, particularly Banach space theory. Thinking of my future prospect, I would like to venture myself into statistics.

However, as I do not want to 'waste' my background, I would like to search for statistics or machine learning which requires functional analysis to understand its underlying concepts.

I found [Bickel et al. Efficient and Adaptive Estimation for Semiparametric Models](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387984735), [Tsiatis's Semiparametric Theory and Missing Data](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387324487) and [Small et al. Hilbert Space Methods in Probability and Statistical Inference](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9781118165522).

Note that I know functional analysis is required for stochastic calculus, theoretical probability, browninan motion, etc. But I am more interested in statistics.

I also found that similar question was posted [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/statistics/comments/9v70ly/functional_analysis_in_statistics_phd/).

It would be good if someone can suggest some statistics books that require functional analysis background.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80547/what-are-important-pure-mathematics-courses-for-a-prospective-statistics-phd-stu,   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/213378/learning-functional-analysis-for-studying-kernels

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Two of your links above are assuming that I want to study functional analysis because I need it in statistics. But my situation is the converse, that is, I have background in functional analysis, but I want to venture into statistics.

Comment: Have a look at Gaussian process es for machine learning book and support vector machines (reproducing kernel Hilbert spaces)

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest looking through the functional analysis literature for papers relating to statistics and machine learning. Books aren't where the cutting-edge results are found, and your background will allow you to understand the functional analysis papers.

In a few minutes on the website for what appears to be a strong functional analysis journal, I found the following papers.

[Hangelbroek, Thomas, and Amos Ron. "Nonlinear approximation using Gaussian kernels." Journal of Functional Analysis 259.1 (2010): 203-219.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123610000467)

[Jenčová, Anna. "A construction of a nonparametric quantum information manifold." Journal of Functional Analysis 239.1 (2006): 1-20.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123606000644)

[Newton, Nigel J. "An infinite-dimensional statistical manifold modelled on Hilbert space." Journal of Functional Analysis 263.6 (2012): 1661-1681.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123612002376)

Comment: All those papers are from a reputable journal: journal of functional analysis. Nonetheless, thanks for suggesting. I didn't realize that there are papers of functional analysis on statistics.

Answer (score 3):

Simovici 2018, *Mathematical Analysis for Machine Learning and Data Mining*

This book might be subtitled "an introduction to machine learning for functional analysts".

Answer (score 2):

A [graduate level book on Statistics and Functional Analysis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521539374).  This post [Is functional analysis and hilbert spaces useful in machine learning? If so, how?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/279468/is-functional-analysis-and-hilbert-spaces-useful-in-machine-learning-if-so-how)  gives some hints&references.

Comment: How stat-y is that book? It seems to be oriented towards probability and stochastic processes (hence the title) rather than statistical inference.

Answer (score 0):

(Not enough reputation to comment.)

Did you take a look at functional data analysis (FDA)? It's a popular branch of statistics. The introductory textbooks probably don't require a heavy math background, but the research done in FDA can be math heavy (if you want it to be).