# Connection of Time Series theory with Functional Analysis

Tags: time-series, self-study, references

I want to learn some functional analysis for time series. I've heard from my professor that functional analysis becomes more popular in Data Science research. Can somebody give me some hints what are connections of Time Series theory and Functional Analysis and where can I read about them.

I look forward for your respond

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/419167/statistics-and-machine-learning-references-which-require-functional-analysis-bac/419176#419176

Comment: I wonder if “functional analysis” (vector spaces with norms defined by Lebesgue integrals) are what you’re looking to do. Do you mean functional data analysis? There may be a connection to functional analysis, but I seriously doubt it’s necessary to get into Banach spaces, etc, to do good work with functional data.

Comment: I saw that 1 step linear prediction uses Hilbert space, so I thought that there can be more things relating to Time Series

Comment: Chapter 2 of Brockwell and Davis---a standard text on time series---is titled "Hilbert space Theory". That's pretty close, although not all, to all the functional analysis relevant to time series---about the first week of a standard functional analysis class. Basically, you view a time series as a sequence in the Hilbert space L^2. This perspective is convenient when applicable but the more probabilistic aspects are not visible.